# Why do my applications keep crashing on Lion 10.7.3?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash

Once every couple of days an application crashes on my MacBook Pro with Lion (10.7.3).  It's also running the newer build that's supposed to have fixed these issues (11D50b).

This has been happening to me ever since I upgraded to Lion.  I brought the MacBook Pro to the Apple store and the Genius did some tests and said there are no hardware issues.  I even did a full clean OS reinstall hoping it would make the problem go away, but it still occurs.

Here's the latest example (below), I just clicked the red "close" bubble in the TextEdit title bar and this happened.  But it can be any application that crashes.  It seems random.

I've also tried creating a new account to test whether it's something unique to my profile but apps crash there too.

Why does Lion keep crashing apps on me?

Below is the head of the crash log:

```
Process:         TextEdit [151]
Path:            /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
Identifier:      com.apple.TextEdit
Version:         1.7 (289.3)
Build Info:      TextEdit-289003000000000~3
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [123]

Date/Time:       2012-02-09 20:39:25.666 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.3 (11D50b)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          74970 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           3
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  88329 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1
Anonymous UUID:                      20CE4128-76AD-4508-94DE-8AC8C5BB9231

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
```

Comment: Could you put the entire crashing thread into the post? For me at least, everything below "a ton of stuff snipped out" isn't the interesting bit.

Comment: Did you apply the 10.7.3 update using the [Combo Updater](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1484)? There were reports of problems from some who used the Delta Updater that was initially delivered bt Software Update. Else, does the problem occur when you use as alternate user account or is it unique to your primary user account?

Comment: @bneely I tried posting the whole thing, but I was limited to 3000 characters so I had to cut stuff out.  I guess I cut out the wrong stuff.  Will remember for next time.

Comment: @jaberg I did all my updates through Software Update, sorry I don't know if it was "Combo Updater" or not.  Yes, the problem occurs when I'm logged in with a clean new user account.

Comment: I would suggest you first isolate whether the cause is related to the Lion build or something in your user account. Create a new user, log into that account, and do some computing. If things begin to crash, you'll know the problem is systemic and you can take steps from there. If, however, nothing crashes, and things appear stable, then you have at least isolated the issue to your user profile.

Comment: I have applications crash more like once every few hours. If the crashes persisted after a clean reinstall and are fairly random, you might not have any other problem than that OS X apps are not perfectly stable.

Comment: @cksum Thanks but I tried that, used a clean new user account for a couple days and the same problem happened.  That's when I did a full OS reinstall, but it still.

Comment: Then it's the build. And in the future please include that info. It is worth so much more than crash logs, which incidentally are quite worthless.

Comment: I've got the same issue. I also upgraded my RAM from 4Go to 8Go. I'll test with the old memory see if it still bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this apply to your case but I had the same problem till yesterday, my new MBP was crashing randomly while using possibly random applications. I have figured it out that its a hardware problem. I had upgraded my RAM from 4GB to 8GB and had a lot of 'invalid address' crashes. I had replaced my memory to the old chips and all is good.

Comment: Is there anyway to test the ram to see if it's good or bad?  Also, this problem only started when I upgraded to Lion -- Snow Leopard had been fine.

Comment: You can test RAM from the terminal using memtest, but I use [Rember](http://kelleycomputing.net/rember/).

Comment: The Genius at the store would have discovered those problems when they tested your machine, which was cleared of any hardware faults.

Comment: Well, I have upgraded my RAM memory myself and when for the first time I've bought the cheapest one it was crashing my machine randomly, today i have changed to a different set of 4GBx2 chips and its all good, so don't be so smart ass @cksum

Comment: Calm down. Read the original question. Read it. He took his machine into an Apple Store. They checked the hardware. Go back and read it again. Maybe you missed it. Calm down. No one's attacking you. I miss things sometimes too.

Comment: @cksum This answer doesn't seem to be targeted at just the OP. Hardware tests aren't perfect either.

Comment: @cksum, sorry if I sounded too harsh for you, I just wanted to point out that you should count possible hardware failure too

Comment: Hi all, just FYI, I downloaded Remember, and it days my memory is fine.

Comment: Apple Store genius determined there was a faulty hard drive and bad RAM in the MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, your problem sounds just like what a ton of others were having. Re-update using the [combo update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1484) from the Apple Web site, and that should cure what ails you. *Do Not* redo your update using your Apple's built-in Software Update.

Comment: If you looked at the version number in his crash logs, you'd have seen that he's already running the fixed build (11D50b). And it makes sense that Apple would have rolled those fixes into their online version rather than further spreading the infected one to consumers.

Comment: @cksum, you're right. Can't believe I missed that. Plus, your solution was spot on. No more helping behavior from my end.

Comment: Just FYI, I manually downloaded the combo update and installed it.  It's only been a day but no crashes yet.  I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Very cool. Hope things stay smooth for you!

Comment: Even though I already had 10.7.3 via software updates, I manually downloaded an installed the 10.7.3 "combo update" and it appears to have done the trick.  Over a week with no crashes.  Thanks!